# Why does promise error captured later than setTimeout error？

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

We all know that micro tasks execute earlier than macro tasks, but unexpected results occur during error capture。Here's the code:

```js
window.onerror = e => {
    console.log('=====onerror', e)
}
window.onunhandledrejection = e => {
    console.log('=====unhandledrejection', e.reason)
}

function Test() {
    function cacheTest() {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject('promiseError')
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log('start throw promiseError')
            throw e
        })
        // Promise.reject('promiseError')
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('start throw setTimeoutError')
            throw new Error('setTimeoutError')
        }, 1)
        console.log('start throw syncError')
        throw new Error('syncError')
    }
    return (
        <div id="test-performance" onClick ={cacheTest}>
            Test Insight:Cache Exception
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render( <Test/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And I got this:

```
start throw syncError
Inline Babel script:3 =====onerror Uncaught Error: syncError

start throw promiseError
Inline Babel script:19 start throw setTimeoutError
Inline Babel script:3 =====onerror Uncaught Error: setTimeoutError

=====unhandledrejection
```

But when I change setTimeout to 1, everything is normal：

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('start throw setTimeoutError')
    throw new Error('setTimeoutError')
}, 1)
```

It work as:

```
start throw syncError
Inline Babel script:3 =====onerror Uncaught Error: syncError

start throw promiseError
Inline Babel script:6 =====unhandledrejection 

start throw setTimeoutError
Inline Babel script:3 =====onerror Uncaught Error: setTimeoutError
```

Is it because setTimeout0 has some special mechanism?

Comment: must be chrome, firefox displays in the same order regardless of the timeout - no `setTimeout` has no special mechanism

Comment: @JaromandaX I have different results in chrome

Comment: that's why I said *it must be chrome* - what's the issue though? is it causing a problem? if you handle your errors properly, then it will never be an issue, will it?

Comment: @JaromandaX For firefox, setTimeout always reports errors earlier than promise, which still does not conform to the cognition. Safari is consistent with chrome

Comment: I think - question can be shorter, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbqc3p2w/2/

Comment: "We all know that micro tasks execute earlier than macro tasks". I consider myself part of "we all" but I don't know this. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Jackson You are right. I will revise it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Riddle looks like setTimeout(0) works as setImmediate, and calls on the end of current phase.

Comment: @Thomas https://whatpr.org/html/4288/webappapis.html#event-loops

Comment: Code you write should depend on the public JavaScript API, never some internal working of the engine. So although the behaviour might be interesting, it shouldn't impact any actual real-world code.

Answer (score 0):

Idk how it works in browser.
I am `node.js` developer, and I know how it works in node.js

I think - `setTimeout(0)` use `setImmediate()` function, and calls in microtasks turn, before `Promise` handling.

There are `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick` functions in `node.js`
so, if you think that `setImmediate` will calls already and `process.nextTick` - in next tick - its not a true!

There is a wrong behaviour in `node.js`, because when developers developed architecture - they made a mistake and mixed up `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick` function behaviour.

so, `process.nextTick` turns in microtasks and before `Promise`'s

I have remade code from author for `node.js` and it works like I said above!

```
function cacheTest(milis) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('promiseError')
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log('start throw promiseError')
    throw e
  });

  // Promise.reject('promiseError')
  if (milis === 0) {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      console.log('start throw setTimeoutError')
      throw new Error('setTimeoutError');
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('start throw setTimeoutError');
      throw new Error('setTimeoutError');
    }, milis)
  }
  console.log('start throw syncError')
  throw new Error('syncError')
}

try {
  cacheTest(0);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

try to call `cacheTest(0)` and `cacheTest(1)`

you will see results like the author have.
(but there will be only 2 errors, because unhandler error already crashes the process)

so in 1st case - the second error will be from `process.nextTick()`
in 2nd case - the second error will be from `Promise`

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/